# err in single line code of (for) and (if) condition

Tags: python

program to reverses all the words in a sentence starting with a particular letter stored in Variable c
i want to know difference between single line and multiple line condition

when i write like this it is working

```
l = "word searches are super fun"
c = 's' 
for i in l.split():
        if i[0] == c:
            l = l.replace(i, i[::-1])
print(l)
```

this is giving err

```
l="word searches are super fun"
c='s'
l=l.replace(i, i[::-1]) for i in l.split() if i[0]==c
print(l)
```

output should be 
    (   word sehcraes are repus fun )
but it is
    ( invalid syntax )

Comment: you can't use `for/if` in all situations - only in `list comprehension` and similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `for/if` in all situations. You can use it in `list comprehension` (or similar)

```
l = "word searches are super fun"
c = 's'

# create list with new words - using list comprehension
l = [ i[::-1] if i[0]==c else i for i in l.split() ]

# concatenate list into one string
l = ' '.join(l)

print(l)
```